# Detect disconnect Winsock C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, winsock, winsock2

I am new to c++. I understand Object Oriented Programming.

I followed a tutorial and put together this Client/Server code. I would now like to add a message to the server when a client is disconnected.

im using vs11

Server:

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

void main ( )
{
    long answer;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVERSION;
    DLLVERSION = MAKEWORD(2,1);

    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVERSION, &wsaData);

    //WINSOCK LOADED

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    SOCKET sListen;
    SOCKET sConnect;
    SOCKET* Connections;
    static int ConCounter = 0;

    Connections = (SOCKET*)calloc(64, sizeof(SOCKET));

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);


    sListen = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,NULL);

    bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Wating for connection..." <<endl;

        if(sConnect = accept(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen))
        {
            Connections[ConCounter] = sConnect;

            cout << "Connection found " << ConCounter <<endl;

            answer = send(Connections[ConCounter], "YourMessage", 12, NULL);

            ConCounter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

void main ( )
{
    string confirm;
    char message[200];
    string strmessage;

    long answer;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    answer = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData);

    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    SOCKET sConnect;

    sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,NULL);



    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;


    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

    cout << "Do you want to connect to the Server? [Y/N]" <<endl;
    cin >> confirm;

    if(confirm == "N")
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if(confirm == "Y")
        {
            connect(sConnect, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr));

            answer = recv(sConnect, message, sizeof(message), NULL);

            strmessage = message;
            cout << strmessage <<endl;

            getchar();
        }
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't detect it with your present code, because all your present server does is send one message to a newly accepted connection, which isn't likely to fail, and then completely forget about that connection., including leaking its socket into hyperspace.

You need to either start a new thread per connection, that will deal with all I/O on that connection including disconnects (signaled by recv() returning zero) or errors (signaled by -1 returns from send() or recv())., or else go to Async or multiplexed I/O, which is two whole nuther kettles of fish.

Comment: so i need to create a socket defined by a variable in a function?

I know this sounds stupid, but what do you recommend i learn about right now based on my situation?

I want to make a c++ program with networking. 

i know Java/PHP/Vb pretty well, and i have no idea what i'm doing with sockets/threads.

Comment: I don't know where you got your first sentence from. It bears zero relationship to anything I have said. I recommend you read a  basic network program ing tutorial, and decide what your program is actually *for.* it doesn't do anything useful at the moment.

Comment: i thought you meant i need to create a socket for each thread. and i would define it in a function using an int at the end of the sockets name... so the name would be variable...

Comment: I don't know what 'int at the top of the socket's name' or 'name would be variable' could possibly mean, or what they have to do with my answer.  You need to get out of the sloppy habit of 'I thought you meant'. I meant what I said. Nothing more, nothing less. I do assume you are capable of implementing the suggestion I made without confirming every trivial detail with me.

Comment: My answer was based mostly off my knowledge of PHP so i could see how I might sound like an idiot talking about c++